# WKWebView: Remote url accessing local files

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I'm using Xamarin.iOS but everything is easily translatable to ObjC / Swift.

I have a `WKWebView` which loads a remote URL (html, js, css) that will then load mp4 videos stored locally within the app. The problem is these videos are not being loaded.

The site uses HTML 5 video tags and I'm setting the local urls by communicating C# with Javascript.

The video paths are something like this: `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F535FA1C-752B-4B46-B237-6781464EE0E5/Documents/../Library/Vimeo/7b2723fa-b0f1-40c5-bc58-d43949273329.mp4`.

This is my WKWebView setup:

```
var userController = new WKUserContentController();
userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(new iOSSiteWrapper(this.ViewModel, () => this.webView), "iOSWrapper");
var configuration = new WKWebViewConfiguration
{
    AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true,
    UserContentController = userController
};
configuration.Preferences.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
configuration.Preferences.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
configuration.Preferences.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject(true), new NSString("allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"));
configuration.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
configuration.AllowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true;
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
{
    configuration.MediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypes.None;
}
else
{
    configuration.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;
}

this.webView = new WKWebView(
    new CoreGraphics.CGRect(),
    configuration)
{
    WeakNavigationDelegate = this
};

// add to view hierarchy...

// this.ViewModel.HtmlContent is a string which contains the html page
this.webView.LoadHtmlString(this.ViewModel.HtmlContent, NSUrl.FromString(Constants.BASE_URL));
```

I have configured ATS exceptions in the Info.plist file.

### Update

I tried loading this simple html string:

```
var videoToPlay = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F535FA1C-752B-4B46-B237-6781464EE0E5/Documents/../Library/Vimeo/7b2723fa-b0f1-40c5-bc58-d43949273329.mp4";
var html = $"<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /></head><body  id=\"page\"><div id=\"VideoBean\" style=\"position:relative;\" width=\"305\" height=\"242\"><video id=\"video\" type=\"video/mp4\" controls=\"controls\" role=\"presentation\" width=\"305\" height=\"242\"><source id=\"source\" src=\"{videoToPlay}\"></video></div></body></html>";

this.webView.LoadHtmlString(html, NSUrl.FromString(Constants.BASE_URL));
```

And the result is the same. The video does not play and I can see this error on the Safari output:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F535FA1C-752B-4B46-B237-6781464EE0E5/Documents/../Library/Vimeo/7b2723fa-b0f1-40c5-bc58-d43949273329.mp4

### 2nd Update

If I load the html snippet setting the local path as base url, it works:

```
this.webView.LoadHtmlString(html, NSUrl.FromFilename(videoToPlay));
```

But as I'm trying to load a remote site, I need the base url to be the remote base url. So a new question would be: is it possible to set two base urls on WKWebView?

Otherwise, do I have any option other than loading the entire site locally?

Comment: If your html content and url is correct in `LoadHtmlString()`, it may be your HTML's problem.

Comment: Please see my updated question @LandLu-MSFT. I tried using a very simple html snippet and that didn't work

Comment: Is it intentional the triple slash in the file path of videoToPlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've done to make it work:

1) Download the html file into the local storage

2) Look for all relative urls in the html file and set the base url on them. I mean something like this: `src="myvideo.mp4` --> `src="https://myhomeurl.com/myvideo.mp4"`

3) Use `webView.LoadFileUrl` instead of `LoadHtmlString` (I also changed the second parameter from `NSUrl.FromString` to `NSUrl.FromFilename`).